# (+)-Bicuculline, what does (+) mean?

Tags: biochemistry

I was looking up some ion channel blockers. What does (+) or (-) below mean?

[(+)-Bicuculline](http://www.tocris.com/dispprod.php?ItemId=2028#.U4t67vnoTy6)

[(-)-Bicuculline methiodide](http://www.tocris.com/dispprod.php?ItemId=159237#.U4t6cfnoTy4)

Answer (score 6):

Bicuculline is a chiral molecule.  That means that its mirror images are non-superimposable.  These non-superimposable images are termed "enantiomers."  When you see a "(+)" or "(-)" in front of a chemical name it tells you that only one the enantiomers is present (e.g. it is not a racemic mixture of the enantiomers).  Chiral molecules have the ability to rotate the plane of a polarized light beam that passes through it. Enantiomers will rotate the plane of polarization in exactly equal amounts (same magnitude) but in opposite directions.

Dextrorotary designated as (+), indicates clockwise rotation (to the right)

Levorotary designated as (-), indicates anti-clockwise rotation (to the left)

Comment: You should also mention that dextrorotary is designated as D (D-Glucose) and levorotary as L (L-tyrosine). But there are some exceptions. L-alanine and a few more L-amino acids are dextrorotary and some D-sugars are levorotary.

Comment: @ron could you please comment why http://www.chemistry.mcmaster.ca/~chem2ob3/nhw_temp/old_old_labmanual/expt1/2ob3-exp1b.html page shows (R)-(-)-Carvone? Wouldn't R (to the right) match with a (+) ?

Comment: @K-Feldspar No, R and S are nomenclature terms that describe the spatial configuration at a chiral carbon using the Cahn-Ingold-Prelog priority system. (+) and (-) describe the direction of rotation of polarized light when it passes through the sample.    There is no relationship between R and S and (+) and (-).